# Azure Notification Hub test send with tags

Tags: visual-studio, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, azure-management-portal

Both Visual Studio and Azure Management Portal have functionality to send test push notifications.

[image: Azure management portal]

[image: Visual studio]

When I do broadcast, everything works fine. But when I try to send it by tag, nothing happens.

I tried to send message with specific tag via .NET object and it also works just fine, both tags list and tag expressions work as expected.

```
string tagsExpr = "mytag";
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);
hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, tagsExpr);
```

Is there some specific format of tags in that fields? I cannot find any information about that.

Comment: No, there is no specific format. Try to send broadcast, then by tag and then broadcast again. If second broadcast attempt will not send anything, then there is probably an issue with tokens.

Comment: How many devices do you have under that tag? Test send delivers to 10 random ones, so it's possible the device you were checking happened not to be among those 10. Other than that, check that the registration indeed has the tag associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot, we could find you send a test notification to Android platform in Azure portal, you said no devices receive the notification. Please [check all registrations and view the tags they are registered for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792122.aspx) to make sure the GCM native registrations with `mytag` are in Registrations list.

[image]

Comment: There are. As I said, everything works normal through broadcast and from .NET app with tags.